# the function returns zero unexpectedly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's a function I wrote. I'm passing in a rectangle object from a figure object from matplotlib. I am getting parts like the x-axis, the width, and the height.

```
def find_disc_probability(my_num, the_bins):
  bin_prob = [(i.get_x(),i.get_x()+i.get_width(),i.get_height()) for i in the_bins]
  for lala in bin_prob:
    if  my_num >= lala[0] and my_num < lala[1]: 
      return lala[2]
    else:
      return 0
```

for some reason this continually gives me wrong values. Am I misunderstanding return statements in python?

Note: I have tried this code outside the function and it works. But still does not as a function.

Comment: Your return statements seem right. I am really not aware of matplotlib. so i assume your get_ functions are behaving as expected. Since you are saying the code works perfectly outside the function. try looking into any indentation issues.

Comment: Also why are you iterating over bin_prob? You're going to hit either an exception or a return statement, neither which is going to allow you to iterate over bin_prob.

Comment: The only way your function can return zero is when the `if` statement is false. So put `print(my_num, lala)` before that line, to check that the values make sense.